# Refreshing the page after Closing the Lightning Quick Action Pop Up/Modal Screen

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-experience

I created a lightning quick action pop up screen that will display on click on an enhanced related list custom button.
So this lightning component is called via a visualforce page, and this vfpage is called on that custom button.
And on this enhanced related list, we can select the records we want to update by ticking the checkbox on each row, and click that custom button where the pop up screen will display.
Everything is working fine, but when I'm done with the update action and close the pop up screen, the data on the enhanced related list table is not refreshed automatically, and sometimes I encounter an issue where after exiting the pop up screen, it will display the pop up screen again instead and this would go into a loop. There are also times it will go stuck on a blank screen after the pop up screen is closed.

This is the code I used when I want to go back to the record detail page or when I close the pop up screen:

---

cmp.destroy();
location.reload();
window.history.back();

---

Is there some issue with this? Are there any more sophisticated way of exiting the lightning quick action and refresh the enhanced related list after?
Thank you all for the help!

///EDIT

1. The enhanced list is not a custom component.
2. When I close the lightning quick action, the enhanced list should be automatically refreshed with the updated values.
3. I used cmp.destroy(); location.reload(); window.history.back(); since I don't know other way to close the lightning quick action, this lightning component is called in a lightning out app, so I encountered error when I use the $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
   4.This is used in lightning.
4. code:
   `handleCancel : function(cmp, event, helper){ helper.handleCancelHelper(cmp); //essentially just calling window.history.back();  function }, handleClick: function(cmp, event, helper) {   cmp.destroy(); location.reload(); window.history.back();       }, handleUpdate: function(cmp, event, helper) {  $A.util.removeClass(cmp.find("spinner"), "slds-hide"); helper.handleUpdateHelper(cmp);   //cmp.destroy(); //window.history.back(); }`

Comment: 1) Is the enhanced related list a custom component?
2) What exactly do you want to do when you close the lightning quick action? As I see you have used `cmp.destroy(); location.reload(); window.history.back();`, why have you used these?
3) Is this in classic or lightning?
4) Share the code so that we can assist you better.

Comment: Hi Nagendra, thank for reaching out, kindly see updated question :)